# How to fix error when creating a button under text input?

Tags: syntax, elm

I want to create a button under these 2 text inputs. I just overtook the code from the docs. But I get this error :

> The `div` function expects 2 arguments, but it got 5 instead.

How can I solve this?

```
-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ placeholder  "Team 1", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", value model.content ] []
    , input [ placeholder  "Strength", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", value model.content ] []
    ]

  div []
    [ button [ style "color" "white", style "height" "60px", style "font-size" "30px", style "margin-right" "70px"]
    ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code, with the children omitted, can be reformatted to

```elm
div [] [ ... ] div [] [ ... ]
```

Do you see why the compiler thinks you're giving `div` five arguments?

Since `view` should return a single element you'll have to wrap the `div`'s in some other element, like another `div`:

```elm
div []
  [ div [] [ ... ]
  , div [] [ ... ]
  ]
```